# Android Google Login - Developer Error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, sha

I have a problem with the Google Login.

I've implemented the *google-services.json* file. The File contains two SHAs, the debug and release SHA. I've inserted both SHA on the firebase settings menu. Downloaded the *google-services.json* and placed it into the **/app** folder. 
The release SHA has to be the right one because I followed all steps to get the release SHA with the keytool!

When testing my App on the Emulator everything works fine but when uploading to the Google Play Store (Beta Build), I get the Developer Error.

--> I know that the Developer Error means that it must be a Problem with the SHA.

I've already used Google Login in another App and there it works fine and I've done the same steps in my current Application.

Can you guys please help me!

Elias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your sha is valid. Note that debug and release builds should be signed with different keys, so you actually need to provide 2 sha chekcksums. Also, look here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

I hope you are not going to upload to Google Play app signed with debug key (which is wrong)

Comment: I used the Sha from the keystore I use to build for Google play. So it has to be the "right" one.
And yes I use two Shas the debug and release from the keystore I manually created myself. And I uploaded the APK to store with the release Sha. With my keystore created.

Comment: I found the Sha now. It was easy to find in the Developer Console under "App Signature".